# css - How to make one column of a table fit the next tallest cell?

Tags: html, css

I have a table with nested tables in one of the columns, I would that column to shrink to the height of the next tallest cell in that row, and be made scrollable. That is, if the cell containing the nested table is the tallest cell in that row, then instead make it scrollable and make the height match that of the next tallest cell. If it is not the tallest cell in that row, do nothing. I have tried wrapping the nested table in a div, and using `overflow: scroll` on it, but I have only been able to get it to work if I set a fixed height on it.

Comment: Try to put ur code in fiddle or codepen so that anyone can work

Comment: I second that, this is very hard to follow

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the height of the next tallest cell and set the height to the particular column using jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following style class to your row:

```
div.myRow {
height:auto!important;
float: none!important;
display: table-cell;
}
```